# show bootstrap toggle text before change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am using bootstrap toggle in my app, and what i'm trying to achieve is display text before the click actually happens. Now no text is shown before click and when i click on toggle it results in "toggle: true" and "toggle:false" .

I would like to display text before the click happens - like this: Music is currently: off, ...and then on click it would change to on / another click off again..

**js**

```
<div class="widget widget-table">
$(function () {
    $('#toggle-event').change(function () {
    $('#music-info').html('Music is currently ' + $(this).prop('checked'))
        })
    })
```

**html**

```
<div id="music-info"></div>                
<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
```

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: hi, do you mean onHover?

Comment: no, its a toggle like this http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ @rick

Comment: I mean when do you want to display the text? "before the click" is litle too generic

Comment: doesn't it already have the ON/OFF text?

Comment: i want the text to always be displayed, just change the values when user clicks on button @rick

Comment: yeh but i want it do be displayed in div/span, next to toggle @AndreMendes

Comment: the only thing that is missing is an initial state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm undersatnding you well, is this what you want?

```
$(function () {

    $('#music-info').html('Music is currently ' + ($('#toggle-event').prop('checked') ? 'ON' : 'OFF') )

    $('#toggle-event').change(function () {
        $('#music-info').html('Music is currently ' + ($(this).prop('checked') ? 'ON' : 'OFF') )
    });
});
```

Check it here... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/wfrLsa2h/

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. now if i understand correctly = ($('#toggle-event').prop('checked') ? 'ON' : 'OFF') ) -- this means that on if displayed if value is true and off if false?

Comment: Good to hear! Have a nice day and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I needed to capture the click event, to validate on the server (with an ajax request) if the user can or cannot change that state at that moment. So, each click on my toggle button fires an HTTP request asking if that can be changed. I implemented the code below:

```
function validateStateChangeToOnhandleData){ 
   $.get("validate-state-change-on.php") .done(function(data){ handleData(data); }); 
}
```

the listener:

```
$('#toggle_wrapper').click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); if($('#fam_statusinscricoes').prop('checked')){ validateStateChangeToOn(function(response){ if(response){ $('#mybootstraptoggle').bootstrapToggle('on'); }else{ alert("It can be changed!"); } }) }else{ validateStateChangeToOff(.....).... };
```

The 'validateStateChangeToOff' is very similar to 'validateStateChangeToOn'.

I hope that it can help somebody.